# Swift 5 CarbonKit pod How to set x Axis and make background color clear for Pager

Tags: swift, xcode, cocoapods, carbonkit

After using Carbon Kit Pod to make seperate tabs for 2 Sections.
Unable to make background color clear for the pager
Eg:- This is my Code

```
let items = ["First ViewController", "Second ViewController"]
        let carbonTabSwipeNavigation = CarbonTabSwipeNavigation(items: items, delegate: self)
        carbonTabSwipeNavigation.insert(intoRootViewController: self)
        carbonTabSwipeNavigation.carbonSegmentedControl?.setWidth(view.frame.width / 2, forSegmentAt: 0)
        carbonTabSwipeNavigation.carbonSegmentedControl?.setWidth(view.frame.width / 2, forSegmentAt: 1)
        carbonTabSwipeNavigation.setTabBarHeight(50)
        carbonTabSwipeNavigation.carbonSegmentedControl?.backgroundColor = .clear
        carbonTabSwipeNavigation.carbonSegmentedControl?.indicatorPosition = .bottom
        carbonTabSwipeNavigation.setNormalColor(.white, font: .systemFont(ofSize: 15, weight: .semibold))
        carbonTabSwipeNavigation.setSelectedColor(.white, font: .systemFont(ofSize: 15, weight: .semibold))
        carbonTabSwipeNavigation.setIndicatorHeight(3)
        carbonTabSwipeNavigation.setCurrentTabIndex(0, withAnimation: true)
        carbonTabSwipeNavigation.pagesScrollView?.isScrollEnabled = false
```

I Want to keep the CarbonSegmented Control to centre having a leading and trailing of 20.
I Tried setting carbonSegmentControl witdth to:-

```
carbonTabSwipeNavigation.carbonSegmentedControl?.setWidth(view.frame.width / 2 - 20, forSegmentAt: 0)
carbonTabSwipeNavigation.carbonSegmentedControl?.setWidth(view.frame.width / 2 - 20, forSegmentAt: 1)
```

Still didn't got the expected output.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **LZPagerView** Cocoapod. Which is very easy to implement and you can customize yourself in less amount of code. Written in Swift.
POD URL: https://github.com/ladmini/LZViewPager

Comment: Thanks for the help, will try this.

Comment: But there should be a way for CarbonKit pod also